# no command named "hive-ig"

Tags: hive, ignite

In this page:
https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/running-apache-hive-over-ignited-hadoop

use this command to start hiveserver2:

```
hive-ig --service hiveserver2
```

But there is no command "hive-ig"

Anyone konw?

Answer (score 0):

It's a script you can create by yourself for convenience, it sets several Ignite specific environment variables and delegates to `hive`. Sample is provided right there in documentation.